# Python reload function from file

Tags: python

I would like to reload a function from a file in a subfolder in Python.
Therefore I would use the importlib.reload function.
I've tried it with the following code:

myfolder/my_file.py:

```
def my_func():
    return 'before'
```

Import initial version of my_func (Expected output: 'before'):

```
from my_folder.my_file import my_func
my_func()
```

> 'before'

Change myfolder/my_file.py:

```
def my_func():
    return 'after'
```

Reload my_func (Expected output: 'after'):

```
import my_folder
reload(my_folder)
from my_folder.my_file import my_func

my_func()
```

> 'before'

However my_func is not updated.
How can I reload my_func?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a notebook, you should restart the kernel.

Comment: Yes I'm using a notebook.
I would like to keep the kernel alive and just reload this one function so that I don't have to rerun all of my code.

Comment: That's a problem on importing from external files when working with notebooks.

You could copy and paste the function in the notebook. Modify it as you want and once you are sure it works, move it back to the external file.